# Django forms and the select field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
class StraightredTeam(models.Model):
    teamid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    teamname = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=36,null=True)
    stadium = models.CharField(max_length=36,null=True)
    homepageurl = models.TextField(null=True)
    wikilink = models.TextField(null=True)
    teamcode = models.CharField(max_length=5,null=True)
    teamshortname = models.CharField(max_length=24,null=True)
    currentteam = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.teamname

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'straightred_team'
```

I use this model with the following form:

```
from django import forms
from straightred.models import StraightredTeam

    class SelectTwoTeams(forms.Form):

        currentTeams = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam = 1).order_by('teamname')
        team_one = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = currentTeams, to_field_name = "teamname")
```

This produces the following html:

```
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='xyz' />
                <tr><th><label for="id_team_one">Team one:</label></th><td><select id="id_team_one" name="team_one">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="Arsenal">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Aston Villa">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Bournemouth">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Chelsea">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Crystal Palace">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Everton">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Leicester">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Liverpool">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Man City">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Man United">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Newcastle">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Norwich">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Southampton">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Stoke">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Sunderland">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Swansea">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Tottenham">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="Watford">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="West Brom">StraightredTeam object</option>
<option value="West Ham">StraightredTeam object</option>
</select></td></tr>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

I would love for the "StraightredTeam object" to show the same as the value part.  I.e. the name of the football/soccer team.

Any advice to point me in the right direction would be ideal, many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a `__unicode__` method (or `__str__` if you're using Python 3) on your model.

```
class StraightredTeam(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):   # __str__ on Python 3
        return self.teamname
```

Note, however, that you shouldn't be using that `to_field_name` attribute in the field definition. The default is to use the ID, which is the correct value to allow Django to set the foreign key correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Label for choice is created in django forms by converting object into unicode (python 2.x) or string (python 3.x). If you want to display `teamname` here, just create `__unicode__` (python 2.x, also you can create `__str__` method and decorate object with `python_2_unicode_compatible` imported from `django.utils.encoding` so it will be compatible both with python 2.x and 3.x) or `__str__` (python 3.x) method that will return string to display as choice label.

Comment: Generally, the rule of thumb is, if both answers are correct - the oldest answer generally gets the benefit of being chosen as the "answer"